# code translation: repeating a string until some maximum

Tags: c#, string, mono

I was wondering if you could tell me what the most efficient way to repeat a string would be. I need to create a string 33554432 bytes long, repeating the string "hello, world" until it fills that buffer. What is the best way to do it, C is easy in this case:

```
for (i = 0; i < BIGSTRINGLEN - step; i += step)
        memcpy(bigstring+i, *s, step);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you consider 1 char == 1 byte ? Because for pure ASCII encoding is correct, but for other encodings it could be wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient way would be to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx):

```
string text = "hello, world";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(BIGSTRINGLEN);
while (builder.Length + text.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN) {
    builder.Append(text);
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: It will be even more efficient if you initialize the StringBuilder with desired length: new StringBuilder(BIGSTRINGLEN);

Comment: @codymanix, you're absolutely right, answer updated. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for posting almost exactly the same answer that I just posted!

Comment: Time used (rounded): 232 ms (no BIGSTRING init)
Time used (rounded): 156 ms (with BIGSTRING), using Stopwatch... wow!

Answer (score 2):

First, do you want the string to be 33554432 bytes long, or characters long? .NET and C# use 16-bit characters, so they are not equivalent.

If you want 33554432 characters, naive solution would be string concatenation. See [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453436/code-translation-repeating-a-string-until-some-maximum/4453536#4453536)'s answer.

If you want bytes, you will need to do something a bit more interesting:

```
int targetLength = 33554432;
string filler = "hello, world";
byte[] target = new byte[targetLength];

// Convert filler to bytes. Can use other encodings here.
// I am using ASCII to match C++ output.
byte[] fillerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(filler);
//byte[] fillerBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(filler);
//byte[] fillerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filler);

int position = 0;
while((position + fillerBytes.Length) < target.Length)
{
    fillerBytes.CopyTo(target, position);
    position += fillerBytes.Length;
}

// At this point, need to possibly do a partial copy.
if (position < target.Length)
{
    int bytesNecessary = target.Length - position;
    Array.Copy(fillerBytes, 0, target, position, bytesNecessary);
}
```

Comment: since the OP mentioned efficiency I don't think it's appropriate to give string concatenation as an example even if you mention that it's a naive implementation.  +1 to the rest of the answer though.

Comment: Yea... I forgot about `StringBuilder`, since Java now converts to use it automatically. I amended my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the most efficient way, but if you're using .NET 3.5 or later, this could work:

```
String.Join("", System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat("hello, world", 2796203).ToArray()).Substring(0, 33554432);
```

If the length you want is dynamic, then you can replace some of the hard-coded numbers with simple math.

Comment: Hm... I'm on Mono, no LinQ. Updated the tags accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: No Linq? Sad!  I would look to Frederic's answer then.  No matter what you do, you should definitely use StringBuilder over string concatenation if working with large strings.

Comment: You know that the ToArray()-call creates an array with 2796203 strings, do you (I know it is necessary for String.Join). Without this ToArray(), your method would have roughly the same performance as StringBuilder, since String.Join is using StringBuilder internally, the overhead for the enumerator is minimal.

Comment: Who says that mono doesn't support LINQ?

Comment: @codymanix: me, if I'm silly enough not to have some references available.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?  Set the StringBuilder to the max expected size and then add the desired string as long as adding another one will not exceed the desired max size.

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(33554432);
  int max = sb.MaxCapacity;
  String hello = "hello, world";

  while (sb.Length + hello.Length <= max)
  {
    sb.Append(hello);
  }

  string longString = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids a loop that repeatedly adds the string. Instead, I "double" the string until it gets close to the right length and then I put the "doubled" pieces together appropriately.

```
static string Repeat(string s, int length) {
        if (length < s.Length) {
            return s.Substring(0, length);
        }
        var list = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(s);
        do {
            string temp = t.ToString();
            list.Add(temp);
            t.Append(temp);
        } while(t.Length < length);

        int index = list.Count - 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        while (sb.Length < length) {
            while (list[index].Length > length) {
                index--;
            }
            if (list[index].Length <= length - sb.Length) {
                sb.Append(list[index]);
            }
            else {
                sb.Append(list[index].Substring(0, length - sb.Length));
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();

    }
```

So, for example, on input ("Hello, world!", 64) we build the strings

```
13: Hello, World!
26: Hello, World!Hello, World!
52: Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!
```

Then we would build the result by concatenating the string of length 52 to the substring of length 12 of the string of length 13.

I am, of course, assuming that by bytes you meant length. Otherwise, you can easily modify the above using encodings to get what you want in terms of bytes.

Comment: Gives me: Time used (float): 315.9855 ms, stringbuilder is still best... though i get your point.

Comment: One test on one input will tell you nothing.

Comment: unless your universe is just this string, and the numbers double up, in which case it tells you everything you want to know!